# use org properties as variables in c or python source code

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm using org-mode to control some charges, using c++ code to balance. But I have to assign the values by hand. And I would like to assign the values via org properties or some other form of assignment by reference. But I don't know how to make the org data interact with my c++ code. Or do it in a more elegant way.
any idea?
my code

```
*  mayo 2022 
** Acario 
   :PROPERTIES:
   :fecha: <2022-05-01 Dom> 
   :empleador: acario
   :horas_all: 9
   :dinero: 80
   :cobrado: no
   :END:

** Acario  
   :PROPERTIES:
   :fecha: <2022-05-07 Sat>
   :empleador: acario
   :horas_all: 8
   :dinero: 60
   :cobrado: no
   :END:
   
** Chiete
   :PROPERTIES: 
   :fecha: <2022-05-08 Sun>
   :empleador: Chiete
   :horas_all: 6.5
   :dinero: 65
   :cobrado: no
   :extra_cobrado: 50
   :END:


#+begin_src C++ :includes <iostream>
  int Pendiente=80+60+65; 
  int Dinero_total=80+60+65+50;
  std::cout<<"Dinero_total Pendiente\n";
  std::cout<<Dinero_total<<"\t";
  std::cout<<Pendiente;
#+end_src  

#+RESULTS:
| Dinero_total | Pendiente |
|          255 |       205 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like that:

```
*  mayo 2022
** Acario
   :PROPERTIES:
   :header-args: :var empleador="acario" dinero=80
   :END:

#+begin_src C++ :includes <iostream>
  std::cout<<empleador<<"\n";
  std::cout<<dinero<<"\n";
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| acario |
|     80 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a named Org table than properties in outline nodes.  You then add `:var myVarName=myOrgTableName` to your source block header. I'm not sure how the table data is passed to a C++ block, probably nested arrays. In Elisp it's nested lists.

Comment: where can i find documentation and examples?

Comment: Start with the Org manual: (info "(org) Working with Source Code")

Comment: 193 / 5.000
Resultados de traducción
Finally I decided to use org mode spreadsheets since it is a simple solution and it gives the necessary power, if I had needed more data work, org sql would have been interesting. Formula i found `#+TBLFM: $falta_cobrar='(apply #'+ (cl-mapcar (lambda (num sw) (if (eq sw 'no) num 0)) '(@I$5..@II$5) '(@I$6..@II$6)));L :: $ya_cobrado='(apply #'+ (cl-mapcar (lambda (num sw) (if (eq sw 'si) num 0)) '(@I$5..@II$5) '(@I$6..@II$6)));L :: $total_horas=vsum(@I$4..@II$4) :: $total_mes=vsum(@I$5..@II$5)`

Answer (score 1):

By using pre-processor, I can include anything in anything, independently of the mode.

RCD Template Interpolation System for Emacs:
https://hyperscope.link/3/7/1/3/3/RCD-Template-Interpolation-System-for-Emacs.html

Example file:

```
* Some details
  :PROPERTIES:
  :AMOUNT:   100.21
  :END:

#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo ⟦ (string-to-number (car (org-property-values "AMOUNT"))) ⟧
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
```

example pre-processed result:

```
* Some details
  :PROPERTIES:
  :AMOUNT:   100.21
  :END:

#+BEGIN_SRC shell
echo 100.21
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 100.21
```

Using the pre-processor would require 2 steps preview, first to preview the buffer, by using `M-x rcd-template-buffer-preview` and second to run the functions or export Org. It could be integrated into one action automatically.